# Tuple index out of range in .format

Tags: python-3.x, format, tuples

I have two arguments that I want to print

```
print('{0:25}${2:>5.2f}'.format('object', 20))
```

But they give the following response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

But I get the desired output when I changed the code to the following:

```
print('{0:25}${2:>5.2f}'.format('object', 20, 20))
```

I don't understand why as I only have two sets of {}. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is the 2 index after the $ sign:

```
print('{0:25}${2:>5.2f}'.format('object', 20, 20))
```

when you use .format in on string in python the number at `{number:}` is the index for the argument you want there.
for example the following:

```
"hello there {1:} i want you to give me {0:} dollars".format(2,"Tom")
```

will resualt in the following output:

```
'hello there Tom i want you to give me 2 dollars'
```

there is a simple example here:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format

so to sum up, in order for your code to work just use:

```
print('{0:25}${1:>5.2f}'.format('object', 20))
```

Comment: Or use auto-numbering by excluding the explicit positional argument, eg: `'{:25}${:>5.2f}'`

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
>>> print('{0:25}${1:>5.2f}'.format('object', 20))
object                   $20.00
```

Note the change of the placeholder from `2` to `1`

```
print('{0:25}${1:>5.2f}'.format('object', 20))
###            ^
```

When you add a third parameter (a second 20), the placeholder `2` finds a value

```
>>> print('{0:25}${2:>5.2f}'.format('object', 20, 20))
object                   $20.00
```

But without the third parameter, an `index out of range` exception is thrown.